# How can I find out what plugins I installed for Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, plugins

I have, over time, installed a number of Nautilus-related packages. Today I've started having issues with a Nautilus feature.

I don't remember what I've installed now so is it possible to get a list of the Nautilus-related packages what I've installed in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all what you need is a list of nautilus related packages, you can get it very easily with:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nautilus
```

E.g for me it returns:

```
ii  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0                                   1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.2                                 amd64        libraries for nautilus components - gir bindings
ii  libnautilus-extension1a                               1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.1                                 amd64        libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
ii  nautilus                                              1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.1                                 amd64        file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
ii  nautilus-data                                         1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.1                                 all          data files for nautilus
ii  nautilus-open-terminal                                0.20-1                                              amd64        nautilus plugin for opening terminals in arbitrary paths
ii  nautilus-pyextensions                                 3.0-1                                               all          Handler of the Nautilus Python Extensions
ii  nautilus-sendto                                       3.6.1-2ubuntu1                                      amd64        integrates Evolution and Pidgin into the Nautilus file manager
ii  nautilus-sendto-empathy                               3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1                                    amd64        GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client (nautilus-sendto plugin)
ii  nautilus-share                                        0.7.3-1ubuntu5                                      amd64        Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
ii  python-nautilus                                       1.1-4                                               amd64        Python binding for Nautilus components
ii  seahorse-nautilus                                     3.8.0-0ubuntu2                                      amd64        seahorse plugins and utilities for encryption in GNOME
```

Trying to guess which ones are plugins or extension is a bit more complex:

```
dpkg -l | egrep -i 'nautilus.* (extension|plugin)'
```

This time it returns:

```
ii  nautilus-open-terminal                                0.20-1                                              amd64        nautilus plugin for opening terminals in arbitrary paths
ii  nautilus-pyextensions                                 3.0-1                                               all          Handler of the Nautilus Python Extensions
ii  nautilus-sendto-empathy                               3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1                                    amd64        GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client (nautilus-sendto plugin)
ii  nautilus-share                                        0.7.3-1ubuntu5                                      amd64        Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
ii  seahorse-nautilus                                     3.8.0-0ubuntu2                                      amd64        seahorse plugins and utilities for encryption in GNOME
```

Comment: I got just this line:dpkg-query: no packages found matching nautilus-pyextensions_3.0-1_all.deb

Comment: interesting maybe you have your guilty package

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112164/how-can-i-diff-two-files-with-nautilus

Comment: above link is about  nautilus-pyextensions

Comment: I try the seconde line and again I got: no packages found matching nautilus-pyextensions_3.0-1_all.deb

Comment: Thanks for having accepted my answer but was `nautilus-pyextensions` your problem?

Comment: when I write both of your answer I just got that line . I mean I can not see the extensions/ plugins

Comment: trying both command and the only result is "no packages found matching nautilus-pyextensions_3.0-1_all.deb"

Comment: I've updated my answer (I installed nautilus-pyextensions and got also this error). The new commands work around the problem and should give you the real list